# How to sort a list of x-y coordinates

Tags: python, sorting

I need to sort a list of `[x,y]` coordinates that looks like this:

```
list = [[1,2],[0,2],[2,1],[1,1],[2,2],[2,0],[0,1],[1,0],[0,0]]
```

The pattern I'm looking for after sorting is:

`[x,y]` coordinate shall be sorted by `y` first and then by `x`. The new list should look like:

```
list = [[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[0,2],[1,2],[2,2]]
```

I can't figure out how to do it and would appreciate some help.

Comment: Also the faster and cleaner answer isn't here. Which would be `my_list = np.array(list)   ind = np.lexsort((my_list[:,1], mylist[:,0])) sorted = my_list[ind]`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) with key:

```
>>> my_list = [[1,2],[0,2],[2,1],[1,1],[2,2],[2,0],[0,1],[1,0],[0,0]]
>>> sorted(my_list , key=lambda k: [k[1], k[0]])
[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]]
```

It will first sort on the y value and if that's equal then it will sort on the x value.

I would also advise to not use `list` as a variable because it is a [built-in data structure](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Comment: No problem. Nice answer!

Comment: Cool, but if I want to 1) sort by y 2@ sort by x, how to do it in this?

Comment: my_updated_list = sorted(my_list , key=lambda k: [k[1], k[0]]), you have to assign that to new variable.

Comment: @LipingHuang That is exactly what this method does. See Antti's comment. If you wanted it the other way around, swap k[1] with k[0].

Comment: in python 3.10 you need to re assign the return value from sorted back to the list: `my_list = sorted(...)`

Answer (score 0):

you can convert list into pandas dataframe before sorting, since pandas give many buit-in functions to work on df. you will have lot more options compared to list

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> list = [[1,2],[0,2],[2,1],[1,1],[2,2],[2,0],[0,1],[1,0],[0,0]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(list, columns=['x','y'])
>>> df_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['y', 'x'])
>>> df_sorted
   x  y
8  0  0
7  1  0
5  2  0
6  0  1
3  1  1
2  2  1
1  0  2
0  1  2
4  2  2
```

Answer (score -3):

Define a virtual index Z = (X+Y) now perform quick sort on Z and based on index Z pick elements (X, Y). Points on circle will lead to same Z (and obviously will stick together in sort results)

Comment: this can't work because the coordinates `(3,11)` and `(11,3)` would give you the same `Z` when in reality they're very different points