# Sort coordinates

Tags: python, sorting, coordinates, point

Can you, please, help me to sort a list (array) of points (x and y corrdinates) correctly?
I used the following function, but it is not always giving me what I want.
Example is the picture attached.

I want the points to be connected in the following order: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5.

However, they are connected in the wring order: 1 -> 4 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5.

How can I edit the code in order to make what I want?

Thank you for the help!

[image: order_of_points]

I want that particular order so that the voronoi region is correctly connected like on the picture below (blue line). The points I have are the points from voronoi diagram defining a specific region.
To be short I will try to explain on the example what I am trying to do:

1. Let's say I have 15 set of points. In each set of points there could be different number of points.
2. The first set of points out of 15 is the set of my interest as I want to get the voronoi region around the first set of points considering all other 14 set of points. Let's say in the first set of points there are 10 points.
3. So to do that I combined points from all 15 set of points, created a voronoi diagram.
4. From that voronoi diagram I know that the first 10 points are from the region around the first set of points, so I can get them and merge together.
5. "combined_coords" are the points of that voronoi region around my first set of points.
6. Now I want to order them in order to define a polygon from them in a correct order exactly like on voronoi diagram.
7. I don't have access to libraries like shapely, geopandas, etc. Only to numpy and scipy.

[image: voronoi_diagram]

```
combined_coords = np.array(
[[ 5766.28476155, 19516.99300136],
 [ 5765.3326747 , 19516.2217852 ],
 [ 5764.33255982, 19515.68693966],
 [ 5762.69492707, 19515.17292775],
 [ 5762.05045578, 19515.29517553],
 [ 5762.02505098, 19516.45055273],
 [ 5762.28121558, 19517.78513446],
 [ 5762.62958104, 19518.74867786],
 [ 5763.31238375, 19519.86920443],
 [ 5763.72620097, 19520.19250031],
 [ 5764.24999132, 19520.88744217],
 [ 5764.65547718, 19521.18117486],
 [ 5765.21676807, 19522.12631202],
 [ 5765.67501467, 19522.40253271],
 [ 5766.79878351, 19528.51536924],
 [ 5766.81357218, 19528.52972979],
 [ 5766.54317078, 19523.59611998],
 [ 5766.92157601, 19525.04371133],
 [ 5767.67457849, 19529.12581027],
 [ 5771.5263795 , 19524.43240175],
 [ 5770.59556598, 19522.45791971],
 [ 5770.45102759, 19521.34643935],
 [ 5769.91919814, 19521.21760643],
 [ 5768.52296931, 19520.39572883],
 [ 5767.63542881, 19519.1100208 ],
 [ 5767.57293753, 19519.06926975],
 [ 5766.99422734, 19518.06749945],
 [ 5766.76994398, 19517.86007797]]    
)
new_points = sorting_function(combined_coords)
def sorting_function(xy_e):
    #step 1
    xl=xy_e[:,0]
    yl=xy_e[:,1]
    xc=sum(xl)/len(xl)
    yc=sum(yl)/len(yl)

    xa=np.array(xl)-xc
    ya=np.array(yl)-yc

    #step 3
    q=[{},{},{},{}]
    for i in range(len(xa)):
        if (xa[i]<0 and ya[i]<0):
            q[0][i]=(xa[i],ya[i])
        elif (xa[i]<0 and ya[i]>0):
            q[1][i]=(xa[i],ya[i])
        elif (xa[i]>0 and ya[i]>0):
            q[2][i]=(xa[i],ya[i])
        else:
            q[3][i]=(xa[i],ya[i])

    #step 4        
    alpha={}
    for i in range(len(q)):
        for j in q[i].keys():
            beta=np.degrees(np.arctan(abs(q[i][j][1])/abs(q[i][j][0])))
            if i==0:
                s=90-beta
            elif i==1:
                s=90+beta
            elif i==2:
                s=270-beta
            else:
                s=270+beta
            alpha[j]=s

    #step 5  

    xy = xy_e.tolist()

    re_xy=[]
    sorted_alpha=sorted(alpha.values())
    for i in sorted_alpha:
        for k,l in alpha.items():
            if i==l:
                check_p=xy[k] in re_xy
                if not check_p:
                    re_xy.append(xy[k])
    return re_xy
```

Comment: You seen to want to sort by ascending y coordinate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a list of x-y coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111798/how-to-sort-a-list-of-x-y-coordinates)

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to follow for your sort. Why do you want the different order? What is defining it?

Comment: How do you expect this sorting to be done?  As a human you can see it, but how can the computer know what you want?  I suppose you could search the list for "closest next point".

Comment: @trincot, edited the post with explanation

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi, no

Answer (score 2):

This sorts by closest distance.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

combined_coords = np.array(
[[ 5766.28476155, 19516.99300136],
 [ 5765.3326747 , 19516.2217852 ],
 [ 5764.33255982, 19515.68693966],
 [ 5762.69492707, 19515.17292775],
 [ 5762.05045578, 19515.29517553],
 [ 5762.02505098, 19516.45055273],
 [ 5762.28121558, 19517.78513446],
 [ 5762.62958104, 19518.74867786],
 [ 5763.31238375, 19519.86920443],
 [ 5763.72620097, 19520.19250031],
 [ 5764.24999132, 19520.88744217],
 [ 5764.65547718, 19521.18117486],
 [ 5765.21676807, 19522.12631202],
 [ 5765.67501467, 19522.40253271],
 [ 5766.79878351, 19528.51536924],
 [ 5766.81357218, 19528.52972979],
 [ 5766.54317078, 19523.59611998],
 [ 5766.92157601, 19525.04371133],
 [ 5767.67457849, 19529.12581027],
 [ 5771.5263795 , 19524.43240175],
 [ 5770.59556598, 19522.45791971],
 [ 5770.45102759, 19521.34643935],
 [ 5769.91919814, 19521.21760643],
 [ 5768.52296931, 19520.39572883],
 [ 5767.63542881, 19519.1100208 ],
 [ 5767.57293753, 19519.06926975],
 [ 5766.99422734, 19518.06749945],
 [ 5766.76994398, 19517.86007797]]    
)

def sorting_function(xy):
    xy = xy.tolist()
    out = [xy.pop(3)]
    while xy:
        dist = 9999999999999999999999
        distn = -1
        for n,x1y1 in enumerate(xy):
            d1 = math.dist(out[-1], x1y1)
            if d1 < dist:
                dist = d1
                distn = n
        print(distn)
        out.append( xy.pop(distn) )
    return np.array(out)
            
new_points = sorting_function(combined_coords)
x = new_points[:,0]
y = new_points[:,1]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I meant @Al_Pacino
Just use this.

Comment: Yes, but..  This is not as cool as it seems, because the choice of initial point can make a difference.  This is close, but not perfect.

Comment: Every code has it's own weaknesess at the start but you made it clear which way to go. It just need a little more effor from requesting side.

Comment: Thank you guys! I tested on this set of points and it works the way I wanted. Will test on all other set of points as I have thousands of them :-) and will update how it goes

Comment: How to correctly choose which point to pop inside "out = [xy.pop(3)]"? Why is that 3 here and how to choose it for other combination of points?

Comment: That's the awkward part.  I picked 3 by hand after looking at several options.  I'm not sure what algorithm would work most consistently.  Maybe choosing the smallest Y value?  The problem is you're optimizing for artistic purposes, and computers suck at that.

Comment: Thank you @TimRoberts! I will try with the smallest Y value, and maybe also with the smallest X value.

Comment: @TimRoberts, tried both options Y_min and X_min, but still gives me a polygon with self-intersections. Probably I will try to add additional function to check for self-intersections of segments. Don't know if there are any other solutions for that

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you only want to sort the coordinates by y value, which you could do in a much simpler way.

```py
coords = [[5,2],[2,7],[3,4]]   # Your array of coordinates

coords = sorted(coords, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Output: `[[5, 2], [3, 4], [2, 7]]`

Comment: It is maybe worth pointing out that the x in the lambda function is the co-ord pair and x[1] is the y co-ord. Another name wouid have been clearer for the not so experienced.

Comment: @strojan thank you for the solution, but it doesn't do what I want. Please, try with the points I added to the post and you will see that the order of points is not correct in order to create a correct shape.

Answer (score -1):

I would maybe create a `class` and `sort it` (walk trough it) like `binary tree or just regular tree` (it's up to you). You can simple start from the frist point and find next closest point (left and right neighbour in terms of X + Y differencies). This could work I believe but has to be tested + slighty modified.

Comment: thank you! Any example fo the code I can use?

Comment: I believe that Tim Roberts just made it clear for you. It works the way I had in my mind.